# Android room use saved Integer list/array to perform sql "IN" query

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite, android-room, android-mvvm

Hi im working with android mvvm room, I have this integer list that is already working and saved on the table in figure 1 this table will be used as reference table for fethcing data in data_collection_table figure 2.

**Figure 1**: refence_table

**key** = string generated in app

**value** = array/list of id will be use to query for any changes on the array values.

```
 ___________________________
|_key____|___value__________|
| key_1  | [1234,2323,235]  |
| key_2  | [1263,1233,2323] |
-----------------------------
```

**Figure 2**: data_collection_table

```
 ___________________________
|_id____|___data entities___|
| 1233  |   event one       |
| 2323  |   event two       |
|and so on..                |
 ---------------------------
```

**Problem**:

1. When fetching the data using sql "IN" I wasnt able to get any data and no error was caught on execution.

Code that I written for fetching the data using room livedata.
sample code return 0 data

```
     @Query("SELECT * FROM data_collection_table WHERE id IN  (SELECT value 
    FROM refence_table WHERE `key` LIKE :key)")
       LiveData<List<T>> getDataList(String key);
```

2. How can query the length of the value in the refence_table using the its key.

```
     @Query("SELECT COUNT(value) FROM tbl_reference WHERE `key` LIKE :key")
    int getCount(String key);
```

Ive already tried to use LENGTH(value) and COUNT(value) in sql also not working.